# can't stop recursive java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to search for the node by using the it's label and add a new node under the target node, 
when I tried to use recursive to search it, it always return a wrong target or return null. 
anyone know how to fix it?

```
public TreeNode getNodeReference(String label){

    if(left!=null){
        if(check(left,label)==true)
            return left;
         left.getNodeReference(label);
    }

    if(middle!=null){
        if(check(middle,label)==true)
           return middle;
        middle.getNodeReference(label);
    }
    if(right!=null)
     { if(check(right,label)==true)
          return right;
        right.getNodeReference(label);
    }
    return null;
}


public boolean check(TreeNode tree,String label){

    if(tree.getLabel().equals(label))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Your general problem is that you call the method recursively, but you don't do anything based on the result. So, when you call left.getNodeReference(), save the result in a variable and compare it to null. If it's non-null, then return the result -- you're done. Otherwise, keep going. The same with middle and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually trace through your code, you can pretty clearly see why it would return an incorrect result. I've marked the code path below if none of the children of the first level of the tree match the label (assume left/middle/right are all non-null):

```
public TreeNode getNodeReference(String label){

  if(left!=null){ // 1: left is not null
    if(check(left,label)==true) // 2: no match, proceed to 3
        return left;
    left.getNodeReference(label); // 3: called, but why? no side effect, no return.
  }

  if(middle!=null){ // 4
    if(check(middle,label)==true) // 5
       return middle;
    middle.getNodeReference(label); // 6
  }

  if(right!=null) { // 7
    if(check(right,label)==true) // 8
       return right;
    right.getNodeReference(label); // 9
  }

  return null; // 10: and finally we're here and we return null
}
```

Essentially, you call child.getNodeReference(label), but that's all you do. You call it. You then discard the returned value and proceed, and therefore your search effectively never descends beyond the first level of the node you originally called getNodeReference on.

So for starters, this general pattern is what you want:

```
if (child != null) { 
    if (check(child, label))
        return child; // match found
    TreeNode childResult = child.getNodeReference(label);
    if (childResult != null)
        return childResult; // match found deeper in tree; this is what you did not do.
}
```

That said, here is a shorter implementation (keep in mind this isn't *exactly* like what you had, as your implementation also skipped checking the actual node that getNodeReference was first called on):

```
public TreeNode getNodeReference (String label) {

    if (check(this, label))
        return this;

    TreeNode childResult = null; 
    if (left != null)
        childResult = left.getNodeReference(label);
    if (childResult == null && middle != null)
        childResult = middle.getNodeReference(label);
    if (childResult == null && right != null)
        childResult = right.getNodeReference(label);

    return childResult;

}
```

In general, you should sit down, take a hard look at your code, and step through one line at a time. Usually, when you do that, problems like this become clear.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it solved my problem perfectly!
by the way, is there any useful information or website for learning recursive?
I found out it is always hard to understand how would the recursive program works

Comment: Hmm; good question. I think it just comes with experience. I have vague memories of an epiphany after a college course in SML years ago -- perhaps if you are interested in more high concept and abstract stuff, you may want to study a functional language such as ML, Haskell, or Lisp. For declarative languages, like Java, I found this in a cursory Google search: http://erwnerve.tripod.com/prog/recursion/index.htm -- might be worth checking out. Think along the lines of fractals, mathematical induction, etc.

Comment: Off topic but interesting, many (all?) programs can be reduced to a finite state machine, which can quite easily be implemented recursively. It's the theory behind programs like http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/tball/papers/xmasgift/ (they're fun to write).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :
You're not doing anything with the returned value from an inner call.

For exemple :

1. Left isn't null
2. check return false
3. call getNodeReference with the label
4. left isn't null
5. check return true

   (return true to the first call but you got nothing to catch it)
6. middle isn't null
7. check...

   ...

   X. return null;


    BOOM!